# HTML5 Video not playing smoothly, buffers again on replay

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, video, html5-video

My html5 video tag is as follows:

```
<video preload="auto" controls="">              
        <source src="http://whatever/sweetvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
</video>
```

The video itself is a 30 second video.

On Chrome(v37) and IE11, 
The video buffers and plays every few seconds. **It does not preload the entire video.**

**But on Chrome:**
**When i replay the video, it starts buffering all over again - This is the main issue**. 
On IE11 it does not buffer again on replay (the desired behavior)

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Comment: Me too. I did a bit of research and found out that unfortunately it seems currently impossible to save a media while watching it and then play it again : http://www.w3.org/2011/webtv/wiki/Media_APIs/Use_Cases#9._.22Use_Case_Nine_.E2.80.93_Watch_and_Record.22

Comment: Although the preload attribute is present in the video tag, not all browsers "listen" to it.
Most browsers have their own implementation of preloading a source in a video tag.

The thought behind this is that a web developer does not know the connection speed of a user, the browser does and is therefore in a better position to take decisions on preloading.

You can find more information here: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/04/12/html5-video-preload/